# python get all file descriptor opening with socket

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I use flask and flask's internal web server on a unix based os. I run it like;

```
APP.run(host='', port=8000, threaded=True, debug=False)
```

I restart some serivces in my code like

```
  for service in ACTIVE_SERVICES:
        command = "/etc/init.d/%s restart" % service
        # stdout and stderr are string which output of command
        stdout, stderr = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,shell=True).communicate()
```

When I stop flask app, other services ,which I restart, start to listen 8000 port. It is caused by file descriptors opening by flask inherited by subprocess. For prevent this problem I try to reach all file descriptors of socket. How can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solving this problem, [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) can be used for getting all creating object. After create and bind socket, you can run this code and get all socketobjects;

```
for sock in filter(lambda x: type(x) == socket._socketobject, gc.get_objects()):
    fd = sock.fileno()
    old_flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, old_flags | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
```

This code prevent inheritance of sockets' file descriptor.

Comment: fcntl is UNIX specific, it is not available on Windows. Is there any workaround for Windows?

Comment: in python3.8 I get AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute '_socketobject'

Answer (score 1):

In that case Popen should be called with close_fds = True.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution for python3.8

```py
def _run_on_start(a_string):
    import socket, fcntl
    for sock in filter(lambda x: type(x) == socket.socket, gc.get_objects()):
        fd = sock.fileno()
        old_flags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFD)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFD, old_flags | fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC)
@app.before_first_request(_run_on_start)
```